# Customized Android Widget

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a Widget which look like photo below:
[image]

Upper part of photo resembles normal state of my costume widget and lower part of it resembles highlight state of the widget.

Widget primary features:

1. Both Normal and Highlighted sates could have a background with **image** and **color** at same time.
2. It could re-size by width easily (for example 200dp or 100dp)

I have 3 questions:

1. Is there any particular widget which could help me to create something like what I said?
2. Or should I create a custom widget myself?

Comment: create a custom layout

Comment: Thank you but could I ask you custom layout of what?
For example a custom layout for a button or any other native widgets?

Comment: create a vertical LinearLayout and add two textview (one for title and description). You can set the background image for the LinearLayout

Comment: Do you mean highlighted state as when user touch on the view?

Comment: No, when user touches and holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom layout with a Vertical LinearLayout and two child TextView for Title and description.

Set the description TextView visibility as GONE , since you need to show the description only on highlight state.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_highlight"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:background="@drawable/image_shape">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello! Iam here to display the description"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, on the code change the description TextView visibility as visible on long click.

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_highlight);

    final TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.description);

    linearLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            descriptionTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Also , you need to hide back the description when long click is released. so you have to have onTouch listener like this..

```
linearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                descriptionTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!

Just another question (maybe looks silly because I'm really new in Android world),

Could I have some of these custom widgets in a activity?

Comment: You can set this custom layout to an activity setContentView(R.id.custom_layout) or include in any other layouts (e.g., as ListView items)

Comment: Thanks,
How about grid view? :D

Comment: Sure . You can add as Grid Items